# WebActivator - access to the Server object / current directory

Tags: asp.net, webactivator

I have a WebActivator bootstrapper that needs access to the `Server` property. Specifically, it needs to know what `Server.MapPath("~")` is.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to just call `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`.

Or if you want to call MapPath on arbitrary paths, use `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/some/file.aspx")`.